# PHP string constants overuse?

Tags: php, design-patterns, constants, anti-patterns, string-literals

I have two particular cases where I disagree with a coworker, whether constants should be used or not.

We use a homemade framework working roughly like Symfony 1.x.

1. Initial code was, in a routing PHP config file for routing, like this one:

   ```
   $router->map('/some_url', array('module' => 'some_module', 'action' => 'some_action'));
   $router->map('/some_other_url', array('module' => 'some_module', 'action' => 'some_action'));
   // etc.
   ```

   The coworker changed it to:

   ```
   $router->map('/some_url', array(MODULE => 'some_module', ACTION => 'some_action'));
   $router->map('/some_other_url', array(MODULE => 'some_module', ACTION => 'some_action'));

   // + in constants.php file:
   define('MODULE', 'module');
   define('ACTION', 'action');
   ```

   IMO this is constant overuse: if the concept of "module" or "action" is ever renamed, it would have to be renamed in the entire code, either written as a string or a constant. Plus, the defined constant names above have no specific meaning, favoring naming collisions/confusions.
2. Initial code example:

   ```
   if (isset($_SESSION['unid']) && isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ... }
   ```

   Modified by the coworker:

   ```
   if (isset($_SESSION[UNID]) && isset($_SESSION[LOGIN])) { ... }

   // + in a constants.php file:
   define('UNID', 'unid');
   define('LOGIN', 'login');
   ```

   In our application, those session vars names `unid` and `login` are clearly unlikely to change. Nonetheless, if declaring constants was really a good practice here, I would suggest at least more precise names, for example `FIELDNAME_UNID` and `FIELDNAME_LOGIN`...

Is introducing those constants really relevant (that is, naming should just be improved), or (as I guess) completely useless ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

After a few months, here are a few (incredible) lines from the *constants.php* file.
I definitely find this a completely useless mess, similar to [this DailyWTF post](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Enterprise_SQL.aspx). Too many constants kills constants.

```
define('POST', 'POST');
define('GET', 'GET');

define('PROJECT', 'project');
define('APPLICATION', 'application');
define('MODULE', 'module');
define('ACTION', 'action');
define('ID', 'id');
define('SLUG', 'slug');
define('CONTROLLER', 'controller');
define('CONTENT', 'content');
define('AJAX', 'ajax');
define('EXECUTE', 'execute');
define('FORMAT', 'format');
define('BASE_HREF_CONSTANT', 'basehref');
define('UNID', 'unid');
define('USERNAME', 'username');
define('PASSWORD', 'password');
define('TEMPLATE', 'templates');
define('UNSECURE', 'unsecure');
define('MODE', 'mode');
define('MESSAGE', 'message');
define('TEMPORARY_SESSION', 'temporary_session');
define('ERRORMESSAGE', 'errormessage');
define('START_FROM', 'startfrom');
define('COUNT', 'count');

// and so on.
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234129/should-i-use-constants-instead-of-strings-even-if-the-strings-are-only-ever-used

Comment: Not exactly related (concerns hardcoded numbers) but worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

Comment: doesn't it always end up at personal preference.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it leads to poor design. I said "matter of personal preference" below, because in those cases, choosing any of the two options do not seems an obvious bad practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a valid argument for using constants like that.

If you accidentally do something like:

```
$router->map('/some_url', array('moduel' => 'some_module', 'action' => 'some_action'));
```

it will fail in some undefined way (note the misspelled "moduel").

If you make a spelling mistake or typo when a constant is involved, PHP emits a Notice, and you catch it right away.

How often that actually saves you is a matter for debate. Personally, I usually don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: It's an argument. However in this case the *map()* method should check required data, and in this case would complain for the missing 'module' info.

Comment: Additionally (even if it's unlikely to happen), if your spelling mistake ends to an already *other* defined constant, the PHP notice won't show up :)

Comment: @FrostyZ - I almost said something like that, but decided against it.  In that particular example, it's likely that map() would default to whatever the current module was, in the absence of a 'module'-keyed parameter.  That could fail quite silently.

Comment: @FrontyZ - Regarding your second comment, yeah, then you're back at square one completely.  Like i said in my answer, doesn't seem worth the trouble.

Comment: After a few months, reading this again... Replying to timdev three comments above: I could argue that the "parameters checking" could simply check for a list of "supported parameters" (required/optional). Then, in case of typing error like 'moduel', some message can be shown to the developer (because this parameter name is not among the function's "supported parameters").

Answer (score 10):

Advantages

- consequences of misspelling constant should trigger an E_NOTICE 'Use of undefined constant', whereas misspelling the string literal would not offer such an early warning.
- if followed to its logical conclusion, any remaining string literals in the code should be natural language, and thus the task of identifying strings to be wrapped in an internationalization translation layer is made a little easier.

Disadvantages

- requires you define all constants whether you need them or not. Not likely to be your performance bottleneck unless you're defining thousands of them though!

Answer (score 3):

And main reason is IDE autocompletion, of course.
With using constants you will not even need to write full name of constant (IDE will help you in this) and you will be absolutely sure that you have no typos.

It's not overuse. For example, I'm trying to avoid using strings in code.

Comment: Autocompletion is an argument. However: either you clutter your global namespace with vague constant names by doing many `define('CONSTANT', 'constant');`, then autocompletion may be counter-productive (may propose a lot of values + wrong values among proposals + you cannot be 100% sure that when misspelling, the resulting constant name is not *already* defined + naming collisions problem...). Either you properly name your constants, like `Router::CODE_ACTION` or `ModelUser::FIELD_LOGIN` and it would be interesting to precisely compare readability, typing quickness, error prevention, etc.

Comment: ... avoiding "magic numbers" and "magic strings" is obviously a good thing, but as any rule, it may have exceptions.

Comment: @Frosty Z, nowadays I don't use global constants, only class-constants. And yes, of course exceptions for this "rule" should exist, or code will be too long :)